# Webpack/React: Convert css in stylesheet in to inline style on element

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, styles, inline

I've created a small react app that uses a number of sass/css stylesheets that all are imported into app.scss

Using webpack to compile everything per usual.  New requirements have come into play that required styles to be inlined to the element itself.

**Current setup**

```
.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 15px;
  background: red;
}

<div className="element">Hello World</div>
```

**What I would like after compiling**

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 50%; top: 15px; background: red;">Hello World</div>
```

Searching around hasn't lead to any webpack modules to be able to do this.  Does anyone have input on how I can achieve this? I can always rewrite, but would try to avoid it.

Comment: I would say, doing such kind of inlining is extremely poor choice from performance standpoint, I would rather put those as a `<style>` into page `<head>`

Comment: Agreed, but the build will end up being email templates, so styles need to be inlined on the element as some clients strip style tags

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<div style={{position: "absolute", width: "50%", top: "15px", background: "red"}}>Hello World</div>
```

basically when you want to pass inline style you should pass an object of styling with key value pairs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thanks for your input but this doesn't help in this situation.  That is the correct way to inline styles in a react component, but that isn't what I am looking for.  I am looking for styles to be applied inline AFTER webpack has compiled css.